# Threadsafe read from a stream

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, naudio

how to read from a stream - a `BufferedStream` without using heavy `locks`? I'm reading audio data from a file using `NAudio`. Since `NAudio` stream have lock on `Read` methods, I used `BufferedStream` as a wrapper. I need only read data. However, I lost thread-safety. How to make stream threadsafe without using locks?
Unfortunately I cannot read data in large blocks, because interface which I use contains method `float GetSample(long)`  which read just 1 sample at once.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. 1) `GetSample` calls `BufferedStream`, which in turn calls some naudio stream? 2) What's the access pattern for the samples? Do threads independently read random samples? Or do all threads together process the file front-to-back? 3) How big is the file? Can you store the whole file in an array?

Comment: I want to call "float GetSample (index)" on my interface from many threads at once. Interface implementation uses internally BufferedStream which is not threadsafe (and also it is wrapping threadsafe but slow NAudio wave stream). File can be extreme big, and  I have already solution that loads file into memory.

Comment: Perhaps could you instead call GetSample from one reader thread, and pass that data onto other worker threads?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used that library, but if I understand you correctly, your disk file is locking because you are reading it, so no other application can read it, is that correct?

In this case, it's not your app that's become multi-threaded, and you shouldn't need locks within your application. You do however have to make sure that the file is opened for read only puroposes allowing readonly access to other applications.

If NAudio offers the full set of parameters when opening a file, you'll be able to open the file with sharing allowed, otherwise if NAudio can be passed a stream to read from, you'll be able to open the file however you want and then pass the stream to NAudio.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: No, I need to solution for fast read for a stream w/o locks by many threads at once. I cannot use lcoks, because I have code that uses for loops to iterate over samples, and lock over each sample is killing me fast.